# deleting observations based on date

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete all observations with date before 02/27/12.  The output data set was exactly the same as the original one, but it certainly should not be.

```
data new1;
set new;
if service_start_date < '02/27/12' or date_of_first_revenue_from_acti < '02/27/12'   then delete;
run;
```

Comment: Are your dates stored as numeric or character ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper date constants, for one.

```
data new1;
set new;
if service_start_date < '27FEB2012'd or date_of_first_revenue_from_acti < '27FEB2012'd   then delete;
run;
```

Second, you may need to convert your variables to proper dates, if they are stored as text.  You can use INPUT to do that.

```
data new1;
set new;
if input(service_start_date,MMDDYY10.) < '27FEB2012'd or input(date_of_first_revenue_from_acti,MMDDYY10.) < '27FEB2012'd   then delete;
run;
```

Comment: i just had the arrows the wrong way. I thought it might be formatting issues, but I checked all of that. Thanks for the help though, your answer is what I thought I was going to need to do.

Comment: If you actually did get it to work with '02/27/2012' I would encourage you to do it properly - comparing strings is a very bad idea. MMDDYY is not the SAS standard date format, so it's not like SQL Server where that is automatically converted.

Comment: okay, that does make sense and that is what i'm doing now. Thanks again joe